# Как поменять название файла, который генерирует AndoidStudio?

Tags: android-studio

AndroidStudio создает файл app-debug.apk
Можно ли поменять для определенного проекта это название и где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно.

Добавьте в `build.gradle` следующий код:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "MyApplication.apk")
        }
    }
}
```

где `"MyApplication.apk"` – название собранного файла.

Обратите внимание, что таким образом будут именоваться как debug, так и release-билды (что, имхо, неудобно).

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант подставит в название `apk` файла тип сборки, имя флайвора и версию:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        def outputName = "app_${variant.flavorName}_${variant.versionName}_${variant.buildType.name}";
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                "${outputName}.apk");
    }
}
```

Если flavour в приложении только один, то эту часть можно опустить.

**UPD:** для gradle plugin'a 3 и выше изменился синтаксис изменения имени apk файла. Теперь это выглядит следующим образом:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = "app_${variant.versionName}_${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
    }
}
```

Изменения:

- `variant.outputs.each` изменился на `variant.outputs.all`
- Для задания имени файла достаточно установить `outputFileName`

Подробнее тут - https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_api